# jquery issue in WordPress backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress website that uses an older theme and I'm having trouble uploading new slider images. I believe this is a jquery thing, but correct me if I'm wrong.

When clicked to upload the image it supposes to display a lightbox but instead the screen darkens and no lightbox is shown.

These are the errors that I'm getting when I open dev tool:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to update the jQuery library the old theme is getting?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Which slider are you using?

Comment: I believe theme developers used some custom slideshow that they created, and jquery hasn't been updated in a few years. I downloaded new jquery version and updated and same thing happens again.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a jQuery compatiblity problem.

There are several methods to achieve that.

The best and cleaner way is to use the ready Codex functions and load the updated version of the jQuery plugin.

#### Codex

Add this line in the page you include the slider:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_js_include_function' );
```

and then in functions.php add:

```
function my_js_include_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script.js', '/path/to/myscript.js', array('jquery') );
}
```

You can read more for this [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

#### "Sloppy" way

Go straight to the page you are adding the slider and include it normally as you would do in a HTML page.
Simply add:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This way you get it from a CDN and you do not need to download jQuery at all.

Comment: Hi Leonidas, thanks for the answer, I tried both fixes and nothing changes. Got some more suggestions? Or maybe you want to take a look directly? Let me know. see the same error happens: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0jyca8dhjwuidw/Screenshot%202015-01-23%2012.33.22.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your functions.php file at the bottom:

```
 function icl_load_jquery_ui() {

 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog', false, array('jquery'), false, true);
 }

 add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'icl_load_jquery_ui' );
```

That should resolve your problem

Comment: Hi Arshad, thanks for your reply but the problem wasnt solved, now I'm getting a new error when I add new field for the slider, I add the field but still cant add the image -  see the error here https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kifxch4jau7rgb/Screenshot%202015-01-23%2013.19.19.png?dl=0

I noticed in js folder that there are files for AVIA slider, so most probably this slider is used